# How to fix graphical error and blurred edges in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome, menu, dialog

I am running Gnome shell 3.12.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. Lately, after a few updates there seem to be some graphical errors, most notably a strange blur around dialogue boxes, menu options etc. I am guessing this is just messed up shadow around the boxes but do not know how to fix it. The red area in the screenshot below gives an idea of what I am talking about. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Could this be related to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/548070/14-04-nvidia-hdmi-problems)?

Answer (score 1):

The 'Drop Shadow' can be fixed by the following steps -

Create the file `gtk.css` using the command

`gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

and paste the following inside it

> .window-frame, .window-frame:backdrop {
>
> ```
> box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 1px alpha(black, 0.7),
>
> 0 0 0 1px mix(shade(@titlebar_bg_color, 0.1), @titlebar_fg_color, 0.00);
>
> }
> ```

Finally, restart `GDM` using the command

`service gdm restart`

The "messed up" shadow should no longer appear.

Comment: Did not work. Output after restarting gdm:  stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.96" (uid=1000 pid=3575 comm="stop gdm ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.97" (uid=1000 pid=3568 comm="start gdm ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")