# 14.04 - Nvidia HDMI problems

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I'm running Gnome-shell 3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04
When I connect the monitor to the HDMI port, video is displayed, but mouse movement, and opening windows, causes some weird clipping effect.
Connecting the same monitor to the VGA port works perfectly.

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor     Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
$ lspci | grep -i 3d
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [Quadro NVS 4200M] (rev a1)
$ uname -a
Linux l03u 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

`xrandr` output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 connected 1920x1200+1366+0 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   640x480        60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP-1-2 disconnected
DVI-D-1-1 disconnected
  1024x768 (0xcf)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0xd0)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
```

I tried installing the `nvidia-331` drivers, but with them Gnome fails to load after a reboot, so I had to remove them.

I couldn't take a proper screenshot because the display fixes itself when `print screen` is pressed. But here's a lame attempt to capture the behavior:

[image: lame screen capture]

**Update1 :**

I followed Fabby's answer below and installed nvidia-346 from the xorg-edgers ppa.

With the nvidia drivers `gdm` fails to load. The syslog contains the following errors:

```
Nov 18 22:31:03 gdm-simple-slave[3182]: GLib-GObject: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Nov 18 22:31:03 gdm-launch-environment][3195]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Nov 18 22:31:03 gnome-session[3249]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012
Nov 18 22:31:03 gdm-simple-slave[3182]: GLib: Source ID 4 was not found when attempting to remove it
Nov 18 22:31:03 gdm-simple-slave[3182]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Nov 18 22:31:03 acpid: client 3187[0:0] has disconnected
```

**Update2:**

Tested the same with Unity and XFCE and the same issue reappears. Gnome appears to be unrelated.

Comment: You mention using Gnome 3.10. Have you tried the Unity desktop environment? If so, do you observe the same behaviour?

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 14.10 live with Unity instead of Gnome, and the behavior is almost the same. I guess Gnome wasn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: Same with xfce.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problems, but I added the http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu and they are much quicker to solve problems with drivers then the standard Ubuntu repositories...

I currently have the 346.16 driver installed and that did away with all that flickering...

Comment: Done, but now `gdm` fails to load with nvidia drivers installed (updated my answer with the details). I also tried installing bumblebee on top of nvidia, but then the HDMI port isn't recognized at all. Any ideas?

Comment: 1/ Add a bug in their launchpad (as I said: they're much quicker fixing things)
2/ Go back one version: uninstall 346.16 and install 343.22 (maybe the bug you're having now was introduced recently)

Comment: Still not solved, need to check other versions of the nvidia drivers... But I feel that I'm much closer to solving it now...

Comment: @YuriPrezument have you solved this problem, if yes then can you share with us, because i am also having this same problem.

Comment: Sorry, never managed to solve this one... Just gave up trying at some point since it was eating up too much of my time...

Comment: @AkshayPratapSingh: have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: @YuriPrezument: see above...